# Spring Boot can't find /WEB-INF/classes/index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I have a problem with my Spring Boot + Angular 6 + Gradle application.
My app looks like this:
Parent:
->Backend
->Frontend
Backend uses Spring Boot and is configured like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BackendApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return configureApplication(builder);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
  }

  private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(BackendApplication.class).bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
  }
}  

@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class IndexController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    modelAndView.addObject("apiUrl", resolveBaseApiUrl(request));;
    return modelAndView;
  }

  private String resolveBaseApiUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getRequestURL().toString().replace("https://", "//").replace("http://", "//");
  }
}

@EnableWebMvc()
@Configuration
public class ViewConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/classes/");
  }
}
```

Additionally I have some dependencies that should be added to run this app from war.

```
compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.10'
```

I'm building my Angular 6 frontend and adding content of dist directory to WAR using gradle sourceSets:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["$webappDir/dist", "$projectDir/src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}
```

WAR file after build looks like this (as you can see, there is WEB-INF/classes/index.jsp file):
[Screenshot of WAR file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfmdv.jpg)

Do you have any ideas why I'm still getting 404?

```
Whitelabel Error Page
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/classes/index.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with a similar problem myself. I *think* that Spring Boot is looking for a `static` directory inside `classes`.
See [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) for details.  It appears for a Spring Boot app you can put your static content (to include index.html) in any of:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

There's a lot of discussion in the comments section of the spring.io link about people with similar challenges. I'm working my way through it to try to get my setup right. https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Your sourceSets would seem to put the Angular content into `main/resources`, but there's no `/resources` directory in your resulting WAR screenshot. Maybe try changing sourceSets to:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["$webappDir/dist", "$projectDir/src/main/resources/static"]
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will create the static directory and then Spring Boot should be able to find your index.html when you hit `localhost:8080/WARname`

Answer (score 0):

## Issue:

> The problem is that you configured, resource request path should be
>   searched in `/WEB-INF/classes/`, and that's why you are getting error on this path `/WEB-INF/classes/index.jsp`

---

## Solution:

Now, if you are using AngularJS and it's a single page application then the configuration should be like:

```
@EnableWebMvc()
    @Configuration
    public class ViewConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/js/**")

                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/js/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/css/**")

                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/views/**")

                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/views/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**")

                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")

                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/views/index.html")
                .setCachePeriod(cachePeriod).resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath,
                        Resource location) throws IOException {
                        return location.exists() && location.isReadable() ? location :
                            null;
                    }
                });
        }

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/resources/static/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".html");
            return resolver;
        }


    }
```

This way you are saying that my resources like js,css,images should be search on their corresponding folders and all the other routes should be served by index.html at `classpath:/static/views/index.html`

---

> - Note that you should probably change above code to match your folder structure. I hope you got the whole idea.